# Angular: What's the correct way to return Observable?

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, observable

I have the following method which isn't working correct:

```
  getProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
      let PRODUCTS: Product[];
      this.http.get(this.base_url + "api/products")
      .subscribe(
        (data) => {
            for(var i in data) {
                PRODUCTS.push(new Product(data[i].id, data[i].name, data[i].category, data[i].description, data[i].price, data[i].amount));
            }
        },
        (error) => {
            console.log(error);
      });
      return of(PRODUCTS);
  }
```

The error I'm getting is this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

Now, I know that the PRODUCT array is not accessable from within the subscribe function, but I cannot get the correct solution for it.

Can anyone help me with that. I want to return an `Observable<Product[]>`.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: initialize your array:  let PRODUCTS: Product[] = [];

Comment: @pixelbits That fixes the undefined error, but it's definitely still wrong: the function is now synchronously returning an observable of an array which is modified asynchronously.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http do some research

Comment: why do you store the results in class instances? Do that class define any sort of behavior? (methods)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Edit:* Updated to account for the fact that the API seems to return an array-like object rather than a true array.

You want to use `map`:

```
getProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.base_url + "api/products")
    .map(data => {
      let products = [];
      for (let i in data) {
        products.push(new Product(data[i].id, data[i].name, data[i].category, data[i].description, data[i].price, data[i].amount));
      }

      return products;
    })
    .do(null, console.log);
}
```

---

Since @pixelbit's comment keeps getting upvotes despite being wrong, here's an example showing why it is wrong:

```
// Fakes a HTTP call which takes half a second to return
const api$ = Rx.Observable.of([1, 2, 3]).delay(500);

function getProducts() {
  let products = [];
  api$.subscribe(data => {
    for (let i in data) {
      products.push(data[i]);
    }
  });

  return Rx.Observable.of(products);
}

// Logs '[]' instead of '[1, 2, 3]'
getProducts().subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error: Property "map" does not exist on type 'Object'.

Comment: @UrmLmn Then your API call doesn't return an array, but some object. What does the actual response look like?

Comment: @UrmLmn Either way, I updated my answer to account for it.

Comment: I'm returning the results I get from querying the database: $stmt = $this->db->query($sql); $product = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
echo json_encode($product);

So it's json.

Comment: @UrmLmn I've updated my answer  to account for that.